# Writing and reading bytes to/from filestream

Tags: c#, filestream

I am working on simulating a **filesystem**. I am having a difficult time reading and writing bytes to/from the **filestream**. I am aiming to toggle the first bit to be a '1' indicating that it does in fact have data in it. I have set up a test scenario to represent what I am trying to achieve.

The problem is that it appears to turn the bit on and write it to **_FileStream**, however, when i go to read it out - I do not see my change.

```
_Filestream = new FileStream(volumeName, FileMode.Open);
 _Filestream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Test lines
        byte[] testAsBytes = new byte[_DirectoryUnitSize];
        testAsBytes[0] = 1;

        byte[] newDirectoryByteArray = new byte[_DirectoryUnitSize];

        _Filestream.Write(testAsBytes, 0, newDirectoryByteArray.Length);
        _Filestream.Flush();


         int bytesRead;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
         char[] charBuffer = new char[64];


         List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
         while ((bytesRead = _Filestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead))) {
                 data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(charBuffer, 0, 1).ToList();

             }
        }
```

Comment: please add the initialization of `_Filestream`

Comment: Your reading code is completely off. You read data, then convert it into a string to see if there’s something (why?) and then convert an empty `charBuffer` into `data` throwing away anything you read. I assume that’s why you see only zeroes.

Comment: I would suggest using [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllBytes_System_String_) and [File.WriteAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You have `Filestream.Seek()` in the wrong *position*. When you open the stream, it's already at position 0. Maybe, you want to set the `[FileStream].Position = 0` after you have written to it, to reposition it at the beginning of the stream. Then, as already noted, don't use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`. You already have your bytes in `buffer`. Read the first byte from it.

Answer (score 0):

You have serval issues here

1.why you create another `byte[] array` - newDirectoryByteArray. Seems unnecessary, you can simply write

```
   _Filestream.Write(testAsBytes, 0, testAsBytes.Length);
```

2. When you write to file the cursor moves along with it, if you want to use the same FileStream to read from a file, you must seek your desired location. Meaning before `_Filestream.Read(...)` you must call, for example. `Filestream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> If the write operation is successful, the current position of the
>   stream is advanced by the number of bytes written. If an exception
>   occurs, the current position of the stream is unchanged.

3. the line `data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(charBuffer, 0, 1).ToList();` will **always** reutns 0 becuse no data is written to `charBuffer` . Your data is at `buffer` which will contaion 1 at index 0 and 0 at all other indices

you can see it with     `Console.WriteLine(buffer[0]);` will output **1** and   `Console.WriteLine(data[0]);` will output **0**